# In Gin framework, invalid character 'P' looking for beginning of value

Tags: go, go-gin

When I use Gin, c.shouldBindJson is not working correctly. I test my REST API in postman and get the error response

> Request

```
{
    Username: "asdasd",
    Password: "asdasdasd",
    Email: "123@123.com"
}
```

> Response:
>   Postman gives me the response

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "error": "invalid character 'U' looking for beginning of value",
}
```

#### Struct

Here is the data struct

```golang
type WebRegisterData struct {
    Username    string              `json:"username"`
    Password    string              `json:"password"`
    Email       string              `json:"email"`
}
```

#### Function

Here is the relevant function

```golang
func (h *Handler) WebRegister(c *gin.Context)  {
    if h.db == nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "code": 500,
            "error": nil,
        })
        c.Abort()
        return
    }


    var webRegisterData request.WebRegisterData

    err :=  c.ShouldBindJSON(&webRegisterData)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "code": 400,
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        c.Abort()
        return
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: i think `var webRegisterData request.WebRegisterData` should be `var webRegisterData WebRegisterData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is of invalid JSON format.

Your request should look like:

```
{
    "username": "asdasd",
    "password": "asdasdasd",
    "email": "123@123.com"
}
```